# How to backup and restore Gitlab CI environment variables?

Tags: gitlab, devops

I would like to manage Gitlab variables from different projects via local files, so I would like to export project's CI variables locally to a YAML or JSON file, to change values and to import it back with updated values.

I tried glab-cli and Gitlab API, but it's to basic, You must process a variable by variable manually, I would like to find a better solution, capable to process all variables at once.

Answer (score 1):

Since [this merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/merge_requests/1161/diffs?commit_id=595f1373655cfb5e3b7c8c6f92ee5df3fe9fbb64#top), you can use `glab variable export` to get all variables of your project.